# Event handler for header clicks in DHTMLX Scheduler

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

We use `DHTMLX Scheduler` and we would like to attach a listener for clicks on header in `week view`, `unit view`, etc. We didn't find a way to do this.

[image: screenshot]

We also need date in our listener with date for which click was performed.

How can we do this with `DHTMLX Scheduler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DHTMLX Scheduler` does not provide an event for clicks on header, so in order to do this, you need to change templates for your views first:

```
var toStr = scheduler.date.date_to_str(scheduler.config.day_date);
scheduler.templates.week_scale_date = (dt) => "<span data-scale-date='" + dt.valueOf() + "'>" + toStr(dt) + "</span>";
scheduler.templates.unit_scale_text = (key, label) => "<span data-scale-date='0' data-scale-unitId='" + key + "'>" + label + "</span>";
// ...
```

After templates are changed, you can attach an event listener to `#scheduler_here` and filter for clicks on header:

```
document.getElementById("scheduler_here").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    var event = evt || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (target && target.nodeName === "SPAN" && target.parentElement && target.parentElement.classList && target.parentElement.classList.contains("dhx_scale_bar")) {
        var dateStr = target.getAttribute("data-scale-date");
        if (dateStr) {
            var dateValue = parseInt(dateStr, 10);
            var date = dateValue === 0 ? scheduler.getState().date : new Date(dateValue);
            var unitId = target.getAttribute("data-scale-unitId") ? target.getAttribute("data-scale-unitId") : {{your unit id in unit view}};
            // ...
        }

        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Is this still the only way to click on a day_date header or has it changed in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

DHTMLX Scheduler provides events which fire when the user makes a single or double click  on a cell on the x-axis (the Timeline view only):

[onXScaleClick](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onxscaleclick_event.html)

[onXScaleDblClick](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onxscaledblclick_event.html)