# DHTMLX Scheduler timeline click on day_date

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

In a scheduler timeline view having a second_scale, is it possible to click on a single date? I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33632200/572801), but I'm wondering if there is an event in the meantime.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [onXScaleClick](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onxscaleclick_event.html), [onXScaleDblClick](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onxscaledblclick_event.html) events for the Timeline view. But in case, when you have 2 scales, they fire only for the second one. Check console in the [snippet](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/33d135e2b) that demonstrates it.

Nonetheless, you can add onclick event listener for the first scale using js:

```
var dateScaleEl = document.querySelector(".dhx_second_scale_bar");
dateScaleEl.onclick = function() {
    var targetDate = scheduler.getState().date;
    console.log(targetDate);
}
```

[Demo](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/7bdd8e0f5).

[getState()](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_getstate.html) is a method to get the active date.

Comment: onXScaleClick is working fine. The onclick event listener added via js is not working but I don't know why. There is no error. I'm also able to console.log(dateScaleEl) but it seems like the click event is not attached.

Comment: onclick event is attached properly in the demo in my reply above: https://gyazo.com/2ced86bd840c370c364eb0aeb7815548 . Please pay attention, that you should get the element with ".dhx_second_scale_bar" selector after Scheduler initialization.

Comment: Yes, I took care about this, thx. console.log(dateScaleEl); returns the whole div but the onclick is not affected.

Comment: It works now. I put your code in scheduler.attachEvent("onLoadEnd", function () {});